# Select() monitoring 3 or more file descriptors

Tags: c, linux

I know how monitor two file descriptors but how about 4 or 5 file descriptors?

Here's how I do it with 2 file descriptors.

```
fd_mon = (fd1 > fd2 ? fd1 : fd2) + 1;

select(fd_mon, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

How can monitor 3 or more file descriptors?

Comment: How are you setting up `readfds`?  When you set up `readfds`, you should determine the value for `fd_mon`.

Comment: I'm doing it this way FD_SET(). so i can just assign a number to select say i have 3 file descriptor can i do it this way.. select(3, &readfds, NULL,NULL,NULL); ?.. thanks,

Comment: You should consider using poll(2) instead of select(2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(fd1 < fd2 ? fd1 : fd2) < fd3 ? (fd1 < fd2 ? fd1 : fd2) : fd3;`

It's for 3 variables you can make it for as many as variables

Comment: `fd_mon = fd1; if (fd2 > fd_mon) fd_mon = fd2; if (fd3 > fd_mon) fd_mon = fd3;` is easier to understand (spread over 5 lines) and much easier to extend.  You can even make it 100% consistent by starting: `fd_mon = -1; if (fd1 > fd_mon) fd_mon = fd1; ...`.

Comment: @demic0de - Poor choice of best answer, what if you need to select over 100 file descriptors!?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `FD_SET` macro to add file descriptors to the set you're passing to `select`. You'll need its pals `FD_ZERO`, `FD_ISSET` and `FD_CLR` too. In your case above, just keep calling FD_SET for each file descriptor and the same set.

Google - "[man select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)", it even has an example! I don't know how familiar you are with *NIX, but `man` (short for manual) is the help system built into the O/S. It will frequently answer these questions about the system calls. You may have to install it in some distributions, for example, I don't think Ubuntu has *all* the development man pages installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

You could just test after you open each descriptor:

```
max_fd = 0;

fd = open(...);
if (fd > max_fd) {
  max_fd = fd;
}
....
select(max_fd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could stick the descriptors in an array:

```
for(i = maxfd = 0; i < nfds; i++) {
     if(maxfd < fd[i]) maxfd = fd[i];
     FD_SET(...);
 }
 select(maxfd+1, ...);
```